# handson table does not scroll to new spare row when max height is specified

Tags: handsontable

Handson table does not automatically scroll to new spare row when max height is specified. This occurs even with older versions:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Nissan", 2012, "black", "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2013, "blue", "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2014, "yellow", "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2015, "white", "gray"]
    ];
  }
  
  var
    data = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
      ['2013', 10, 11, 12, 13],
      ['2014', 20, 11, 14, 13],
      ['2015', 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ],
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;
  
  hot = Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
        minSpareRows:1,
        height : 130,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true
  });
  
  hot.selectCell(2,2);
  
  function bindDumpButton() {
      if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
        return;
      }
  
      Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {
  
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
  
        if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
          var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
          var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
          var hot = window[instance];
          console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
        }
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();

});
```

```css
<!-- Copied from http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/demo-highlighting-current.html -->
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue -->

<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? Do you want a way to scroll to the bottom? You can just use `container.scrollTo(container.height)` where `container.height` is the height of the `container`; `container.height` might not be the correct syntax, I forget what it is.

Comment: My understanding is Handson table should automatically scroll instead of us explicitly scrolling down. And this happens only if you specify max height property in Handson table